# Why does this img tag code work in Firefox and not Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, firefox

**Can anyone explain why this image tag code works in Firefox and not Chrome**?

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/1385770342/picture?size=small">
```

In **Chrome**, in the network tab, when the image is requested it receives a **307** "internal redirect" response from the server, then returns a "**data:image**" response containing the image, but the image does not get shown on the page.

[image: the network tab data when a test page featuring just that img tag is loaded in Chrome]

In **Firefox**, when the image is requested, it returns a **302** (found) response, and returns the image, and the image shows ok on the page.

[image: the network tab data when a test page featuring just that img tag is loaded in firefox]

I'm using the latest stable versions of both chrome and firefox. Can anyone explain why this happens? Is it a browser bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have adblock in crome, try turning it off. I had this problem too and that fixed mine.

Comment: thanks, you were right, i had ghostery installed on chrome, but not on firefox, when i disabled ghostery, the image loaded ok, thanks dude! :D